# Tailor dependencies to ES or CJS with Rollup

Tags: javascript, node.js, rollup

I have a NPM package (private) which works in both a browser and Node environment.

This is done by creating separate bundles via Rollup for ES and CJS, so the output looks like:

```
dist/ejs/index.js // Import this for your browswer environments
dist/cjs/index.js // Use this for Node environments
```

Pretty standard. Now I'm adding a dependency to this, which follows the same bundling pattern.

I can import the library like so:

```
import { externalLibrary } from "@external/ejs/externalLibrary";
```

All is good in a browser environment. But now this does not work in a Node environment, as what I'm importing is not CJS.

I could change the way I import the library to `require` and target the `cjs` bundle:

```
const { externalLibrary } = require("@external/cjs/externalLibrary");
```

And while this works in both environments, I don't think it's optimal.

Is there a better way of doing this? Some configuration that I could specify when exporting the CJS bundle?

```
module.exports = {
  input: 'src/main.js',
  output: {
    file: 'bundle.js',
    format: 'cjs'
    // Behaviour here for @external/cjs/externalLibrary ?
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I overlooked the `package.json` config. You can specify different entry files depending on the build here:

```
{
  ...
  "main": "dist/cjs/index.js",
  "module": "dist/ejs/index.js",
  ...
}
```

Then I removed the implicit import of the EJS file, and targeted just the package:

```
// Before:
import { externalLibrary } from "@external/dist/ejs/externalLibrary";

// After:
import { externalLibrary } from "@external";
```

This then ensures either the CJS or ES build is used, depending on the environment using the package.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you already found the solution for this, but even with old import style

```
import { externalLibrary } from "@external/dist/ejs/externalLibrary";
```

you should be able to target appropriate formats for `cjs` vs `esm`. With rollup, you would have to configure the `output` config to be an array of objects with appropriate format set. For example:

```
module.exports = {
    input: 'src/main.js',
    output: [{ file: 'dist/index.cjs.js', format: 'cjs' }, 
             { file: 'dist/index.esm.js', format: 'es'  }],
}
```

Also, being an author of [klap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/klap), I would recommend giving it a try as it would bring in lot of other optimizations by default.